# Made commit while resolving git rebase conflicts, can't continue

Tags: git, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

We were rebasing a git branch, using `git rebase master`, when some conflicts were thrown. After resolving the conflicts, my coworker (out of habit) did a `git commit -am "commit msg"` instead of a `git add` operation. Now, git rebase can not continue. How do I recover from this?

```
$ git branch 
* (no branch)
  groups
  groups_bkp
  master
$ git rebase --continue
Applying: add and remove participants from group
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty simple, all I had to do was to soft reset the last commit, just like we would if we were [removing the last commit from the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/1860929). (Note that the HEAD points to `(no branch)` at the moment)

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
$ git status 
# Not currently on any branch.
# You are currently rebasing.
#   (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   layer.py
#   modified:   __init__.py
#   modified:   leave.py
#   modified:   add.py
#   new file:   add_success.py
#   modified:   remove.py
#   new file:   remove_success.py
#
$ git branch
* (no branch)
  groups
  master
```

After that, I added the changes and continued with the rebase using `git rebase --continue` which worked all right

```
$ git add .
$ git rebase --continue
Applying: add and remove participants from group
$ git branch
* groups
  master
```

Since the conflicts were in large number, we really didn't want to use `git rebase --abort` (and I'm not sure if it would have worked either, after that commit)